# How can I see which character has finished a certain level?

Tags: nintendo-switch, super-mario-3d-world

I've played most of the levels in Super Mario 3D World with Princess Peach and after I've got Rosalina, then with her. If I want to reach the golden stars for the levels, I have to play each level with all five characters: Mario, Luigi, Toad, Princess Peach, Rosalina.

But how can I see which character has already finished that level? Is there some hidden statistic that I haven't found yet? I don't want to waste time by replaying with a redundant character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After unlocking **World Crown** you should be able to see a character checklist for each level.

For reference, [World Crown](https://www.mariowiki.com/World_Crown) is:

> unlocked after every Green Star and stamp are collected as well as getting the golden flag by reaching the top of the Goal Pole for every level.

According to Gamefaqs and Reddit.

Comment: I think that the info box that pops up before entering a level also shows the same info as this detailed level view you noted, including which characters have beaten the level. Helpful to show you quickly whether or not to switch characters before the level starts.